# Slow updating record on heroku postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a rails app hosted on heroku with their postgres database add-on. I can't figure out why sometimes updating a record on users table is getting slow. It's always slow, but it happens as often as well. I took couple seconds for just updating a simple SQL update:

```
app postgres.17285 - - [BRONZE] duration: 8601.616 ms  execute <unnamed>: UPDATE "users" SET "latitude" = 40.8052049006174, "longitude" = -73.96590407672643 WHERE "users"."id" = 1
```

I have also index on User model:

```
add_index "users", ["latitude", "longitude"], name: "index_users_on_latitude_and_longitude", using: :btree
```

There are only about 90 records in DB, so I don't think is getting slow because of updating index.

[image]

Comment: did you happen to find the cause of the issue?